# The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

I have used entity framework with code first approach.

when I am trying to pass record one by one Fromdate to Todate, 1st time its work, after it gives error like: "The property 'ID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified."

```
        var fd = todaycooked.CookDate; // 2016-07-01
        var td = todaycooked.ToCookDate; //2016-11-01

       for (var date = fd; date <= td; date = date.AddDays(1))
        {
            var product = db.Products.Find(todaycooked.ProductID);
            product.Qty = product.Qty + todaycooked.QTY;
            todaycooked.Product = product;
            todaycooked.CookDate = date;
            db.TodayCookeds.Add(todaycooked);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: post the complete stack trace.

Comment: also post your whole model class.

Comment: What is `todaycooked`? Your `for` loop is adding the same object to the database multiple times

Comment: todaycooked is my model object.

Comment: @mohitkotak so... if that is your model object: *why are you adding it multiple times*? Is that meant to be one per record? if so: `new` the `todaycooked` once per `for` iteration; if not: only add it once!

Comment: Yes, but where is it declared. The first iteration of the `for` loop adds it to the context and saves it (so it now has an ID). In subsequent iterations, you then add the same object (with different property values but the same ID) to the context and try to save it (hence the error). Best guess is you need to initialize a instance of the model in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `Product` and `CookDate` once per day, so I *assume* you want one record per day - which means you mean one *object* per day. I suspect you actually want something like:

```
var fd = todaycooked.CookDate; // 2016-07-01
var td = todaycooked.ToCookDate; //2016-11-01

// this doesn't change per day, so only fetch it once
var product = db.Products.Find(todaycooked.ProductID);

for (var date = fd; date <= td; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    var toAdd = todaycooked.Clone(); // TODO: add a suitable clone method
    toAdd.Product = product;
    toAdd.CookDate = date;
    db.TodayCookeds.Add(toAdd);
    product.Qty = product.Qty + todaycooked.QTY;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, you can probably also get away with moving the `db.SaveChanges()` to **outside** of the loop, which would make the whole thing atomic (rather than risking getting the first 4 of 8 days saved, then an error):

```
...
for (var date = fd; date <= td; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    ...
}
db.SaveChanges();
```